# Limiting 'ls' command output in s3fs

Tags: amazon-s3, s3fs

My Amazon S3 bucket has millions of files and I am mounting it using `s3fs`. Anytime a `ls` command is issued (not intentionally) the terminal hangs.

Is there a way to limit the number of results returned to 100 when a `ls` command is issued in a `s3fs` mounted path?

Answer (score 2):

Try goofys (https://github.com/kahing/goofys). It doesn't limit the number of item returned for ls, but `ls` is about 40x faster than s3fs when there are lots of files.

Comment: Recent versions of s3fs include optimizations to improve ls but it still issues one HEAD request per file.  goofys avoids this cost and is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use `s3fs` in production situations. Amazon S3 is not a filesystem, so attempting to mount it can lead to some synchronization issues (and other issues like you have experienced).

It would be better to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which has commands to list, copy and sync files to/from Amazon S3. It can also do partial listing of S3 buckets by path.